# I want a slide deck as dense as a chalk board in a real lecture. How do I get Beamer-style overlays without Beamer?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I've decided I'm fed up with the standard Powerpoint-esque slide decks and want to instead produce slides for my math talks that look like what I might produce giving a "chalk talk".  In particular, I'm imagining much more dense text, probably in two columns given the aspect ratio of projectors nowadays, a much smaller font, but also slides staying up much longer than is typical of slides produced in the Powerpoint style.

I almost have exactly what I want simply using the amsart documentclass, two columns, and some geometry package magic to make the page the same size as in Beamer and to get rid of headers/footers/etc.  In particular, a massive improvement over using, say the beamer column mechanism is that I don't need to solve the problem of laying out the text across slides or even within.  I get to introduce theorems, definitions, examples, equations, etc., and latex naturally handles the problem of splitting up this all into discrete slides because the slides are actually just pages.

What I have lost, though, is the ability to do overlays/build-ins. It's very daunting to the modern audience to be faced, all of a sudden, with a large, dense, screen of text.  I feel what I need, at a minimum, is something akin to the \pause functionality in beamer.  I'd be perfectly willing to be forced to introduce \marks to tell such a \pause function where to "rewind", although I'd like something as light weight as possible.

I've started reading up on TeX but I have nowhere near the ninja skills to pull this off.  Any ideas out there for how to get started?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want a beamer presentation or an article as the final product. For example, it's the opposite of the presentation rules of thumb to fill the slide with text.

Comment: You've made two points here: 

(Re: beamer or article) I'd be happy with either, but a beamer solution should not require that I layout the text manually into columns or manually decide how to split text across slides.  An article solution needs to provide me with some means of doing overlays.

(Re: against rules of thumb)  I've decided to reject these rules of thumb, but this is my stackexchange post, so I get to pose whatever I like, don't I? ;)

Comment: I guess it would be more easy to teach beamer the dense layout than to teach overlay commands to article. The multicol package might be a good start to get dense columns. Splitting across slides can be realized with beamers allowframesplit (which, however, does not work together with overlays).

Comment: Sure, no objection about that but if it's going to be article then why do you need overlay methods is the part that eludes me.

Comment: (re: percusse) It's a presentation, written without regard for slide boundaries (i.e., like an article).  (re: Daniel) I thought that might be the case, but perhaps there's a way to get a simple notion of overlay implemented.

Comment: "Dense layout" of slides is a no-no-**no**. Your slides should just give keywords/titles, not read like normal text. You can use slides for complex equations, if you like. The principal text for your audience is the paper, not the slides. Beamer has facilities to use the same file for slides and articles, but I haven't used it.